# Facebook Search API, keyword search does not display posts made in a page but only in a profile

Tags: facebook, api, search, keyword

I am using the facebook search API to find posts that include my keyword. I noticed that the posts returned always belong to facebook profiles but never facebook pages. To back that up, I searched for keywords of low frequency which I spotted in pages but the API did not return them.

Is there any way I can search by keyword and get posts from pages too ?

Answer (score 0):

Taking a look at [the documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/search/): Just search with `&type=post`.  From that documentation:

> All public posts: `https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=watermelon&type=post`

Comment: The facebook documentation isn't that great source of valid information. I am searching with type=post but it still misses the pages posts and some profile posts too that include the keyword.

Comment: @JohnPapsi I am having the same exact problem, did you overcome this?